# Is there a way to control explorer.exe?

Tags: python, explorer

I am creating a desktop helper, and I was wondering whether there was a way to "see" what explorer.exe does and respond to that. For example, if you could monitor whenever a user opened a specific folder. I would prefer a way in python as that is the main language of my project, but if there's a way in another language, then I'd probably be able to incorporate it.

Comment: A little more information would be helpful, but pywin32 is probably a good place to start.